# Why isn't Corel Aftershot 3 opening my RAW file?

Tags: post-processing, raw, troubleshooting, nikon-d3400, corel

I have photos shot in RAW+JPEG taken with a Nikon D3400 that I have been trying to open and process in Corel Aftershot 3 (not AfterShot Pro) with no success. The photos are saved as .nef files.

Here's how I've tried to open the file so far:

- In the File System tab I used the directory to select the folder with
  the RAW photos, nothing happens -- I see no pictures in either
  standard view or thumbnail view; however, if I select a folder with
  .jpg photos, I can see the .jpg photos and open them.
- If I use the file tab to open a photo, a .jpg photo will open but not
  a .nef photo, even the same photo saved in two different versions in
  the same folder.
- If I go to file manager on my computer and right-click the .jpg
  version of a file, and select open with AfterShot, it will open, but
  not the .nef version.
- Whether the files were imported via another software or whether I am
  trying to access the photos from the SD card makes no difference.

None of these methods to open the file worked so I began troubleshooting the software and these are the solutions I've tried that haven't worked:

- I've gone to File > Preferenceces > Import and Cache and have tried
  checking and unchecking the box to "Create Previews ..." and neither
  checking nor unchecking has made a difference.
- I've updated the software and was sure that was the solution since it gave me the option to select the files types I wanted to be opened by default. That didn't work either, but I could see an image preview count on the bottom left so it looked like it tried but in the end it showed 0 images.

Searching the AfterShot website did not provide me with any solutions other than those mentioned above.  So I tried chat. The agent opened a ticket for me, but my question hasn't been answered yet.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently (though not actually apparent) you have to install the profile for your camera first.

Here is the answer I got from the help desk:

In AfterShot

> go to "Get More tab (usually shown at the right side with an asterisk)
>
> > Camera Profiles > click "Free" for Model of your Camera > proceed with the installation.

Before I finally got that answer, I discovered this way of getting this necessary download:

Go to the Corel Discovery Center website to the Aftershot Pro download page and download the AfterShot profile for your camera. If you go to the main page and type "Aftershot download" in the search, that will get you to the download page which is
http://learn.corel.com/aftershot-pro-downloads/

It says for AfterShot Pro, but it worked for me for AfterShot 3, the standard version.

On that same page there is a link to their instructions for once you’ve saved the profile. The instructions are as follows:

> AfterShot Pro 3 Camera Profile Installation instructions:
>
> 1. In AfterShot Pro 3, click ‘File’ > ‘Install Camera...’
> 2. Navigate to your ‘Downloads’ folder (or the folder you saved it to)
> 3. Select the Camera Profile file
> 4. Click ‘Open’
> 5. Click ‘Install’
> 6. Upon relaunch, you will have support for the camera you installed.

Why this solution doesn’t come up when searching the AfterShot support page, I don’t know.